# Emacs Lisp, how to monitor changes of a file/directory

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for a way to check periodically if a files under a certain directory were changed from the last check (a functionality symilar to FAM daemon or to gio.monitor_directory). In emacs lisp.

- Are there any library/snippet that provide this functionality?
- If not, how can I implement such a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(defun install-monitor (file secs)
  (run-with-timer
   0 secs
   (lambda (f p)
     (unless (< p (second (time-since (elt (file-attributes f) 5))))
       (message "File %s changed!" f)))
   file secs))

(defvar monitor-timer (install-monitor "/tmp" 5)
  "Check if /tmp is changed every 5s.")
```

To cancel,

```
(cancel-timer monitor-timer)
```

#### Edit:

As mentioned by mankoff, the above code snippet monitors file modification in the last 5 seconds, instead of since last check.  To achieve the latter, we will need to save the attributes each time we do the checking.  Hope this works:

```
(defvar monitor-attributes nil
  "Cached file attributes to be monitored.")

(defun install-monitor (file secs)
  (run-with-timer
   0 secs
   (lambda (f p)
     (let ((att (file-attributes f)))
       (unless (or (null monitor-attributes) (equalp monitor-attributes att))
         (message "File %s changed!" f))
       (setq monitor-attributes att)))
   file secs))

(defvar monitor-timer (install-monitor "/tmp" 5)
  "Check if /tmp is changed every 5s.")
```

Comment: This code snippet works sometimes, but not always, and does not technically meet the request of 'since last check'. For example, emacs suspended (or computer asleep), file updated (in DropBox), computer wakes up, file is downloaded with update timestamp, emacs checks, and looks for change not since last check, but in last 5 seconds, and misses the update file. For some reason, it is not working for me most of the time, and never after wake. Can you suggest an improvement?

Answer (score 2):

Emacs links with various filesystem watcher libraries and presents a unified interface in [`filenotify.el`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Notifications.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a proper solution but maybe a couple of pointer to get you on the right direction.

According to some quick googling it seems that dbus has an inotify interface built-ins. Since latest version of emacs you can access to dbus interface via Emacs lisp (under Linux at least) maybe you can plug all of this together to make it works. See an example here about using dbus with Emacs :

http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/01/using-d-bus-example.html